# transforming function based view to class based view

Tags: python, django

I think it should be simpler but here's my function based view with filter

```
def withSub(request):
    post = Post.objects.filter(with_or_without_sub='WS')
    paginator = Paginator(post, 2)
    page = request.GET.get('page') 
    post = paginator.get_page(page)

    content_dict = {
        'posts':post,
        'paginator':paginator

    }
    return render(request, 'community/withSub.html', content_dict)
```

I simply want to switch it to class based view in a format as below, I just want to put filter to Post model as I did in function view

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
```

Comment: what is the problem you're having?

Comment: These two views aren't the same at all. Why are you doing all that extra stuff in the get_context_data method? Why don't you just use the logic you had in the function one?

Comment: @KostasLivieratos db not found I scratched mine out of  frustration

Comment: @DanielRoseman I simply want to change   model=post in classbased view to such that  post = Post.objects.filter(with_or_without_sub='WS')

Comment: So, again, why didn't you do that? Why all that messing about with Vote?

Comment: @DanielRoseman okay I edited the question, do you know how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be something like the follows. You might need to test and debug. The `request.GET` is used, so it's get.

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community/home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        post = Post.objects.filter(with_or_without_sub='WS')
        paginator = Paginator(post, 2)
        page = request.GET.get('page') 
        post = paginator.get_page(page)

        content_dict = {
            'posts':post,
            'paginator':paginator

        }

        context = self.get_context_data()
        context.update(content_dict)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customise the queryset, use the `queryset` attribute:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(with_or_without_sub='WS')
    template_name = 'community/home.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

You get either set a specific queryset, like this:

```
queryset = Post.objects.filter(with_or_without_sub='WS')
```

or if there's more complex logic eventually involved, you can override the `get_queryset()` method of the view, like this:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community/home.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(with_or_without_sub='WS', ...)
```