# Transform function to class based view (recall same site)

Tags: django, django-views

Very similar to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516479/transforming-function-based-view-to-class-based-view) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030566/how-to-transform-this-function-based-view-to-class-based-view) I want to transform my view. The difference is that I want to return to the same page and I have problems adjusting my urls.py (I think):

So on the `product_all.html` I press a button and end up on the same page after the product was deleted:

```
def delete_product(request, pk):
    Product.objects.filter(id=pk).delete()
    context = {'Product': Product.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'gbkiosk/product_all.html', context)
```

urls.py:

```
path("product_delete/<int:pk>", views.delete_product, name='product-delete'),
```

I wanted to recreate that using a `TemplateView`:

```
class DeleteProduct(TemplateView):
    template_name = "gbkiosk/device_all.html"
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        Product.objects.filter(id=kwargs["product_id"]).delete()
        context["products"] = Product.objects.all()
        return context
```

but what would the corresponding urls.py entry be?:

```
path("product_delete/<int:product_id>", views.DeleteProduct.as_view(), name="product-delete")
```

This will not return me to `product_all.html` after clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
class ProductDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Product
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('product-list')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductDeleteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(kwargs)
        return(context)
```

urls:

```
path("product_delete/<int:pk>", views.ProductDeleteView.as_view(), name='product-delete'),
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `ListView` to list the products and a `DeleteView` to delete the ones you like. That's cleaner.

So, it'd be something like:

**views.py**

```
class Products(ListView):
    model = Product


class ProductDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Product
    success_url = reverse_lazy('product-list')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from products.views import ProductListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product-list'),
    path('<int:pk>', ProductDeleteView.as_view(), name='product-delete'
]
```

Comment: this put me on the right track. I posted an answer.